# How PHP treats for and foreach values?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

Suppose `getCustomers` function gets customers from data base as an array(). Because Data Base is in a live system, `getCustomers` results may vary. How php treats these two codes:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count(getCustomers());++$i){
    ...
}
```

---

```
foreach (getCustomers() as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

Is `getCustomers()` called once after executing each code or it is called in each loop?

Comment: First: every loop.  Second: once. You could of course have tested this with a tiny function....

Comment: Why don't you try it first? It could've taken you less time, that it took to write this question

Comment: I've tried it, but it's such an important piece of code that I decided to be on the safe side. Some times there are unexpected exceptions.

Comment: Testing things like this for yourself will teach you much more than asking here. Don't be afraid to experiment with code to work out how your chosen language works. That's how the experts became experts.

Comment: thanks, It seems I should be more brave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your for() loop, getCustomers() is being called again every iteration, as is count(); in the foreach() loop it is being called only once